# Method signature Refactor for Dart/Flutter - available in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Using Android Studio 3.6.1 with Dart / Flutter.

I don't see an option to Refector > Change Signature for Methods.

Is this not supported?  Or only in Intellij IDEA?

Normally this would be a Ctrl + F6 shortcut and available on context menu or main menu, but it's missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an open feature request in the Dart SDK issue tracker, but there doesn't seem to be much progress.
However, you can help raise the priority by upvoting the initial issue comment with a :thumbsup: reaction:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39842

Comment: upvoted. Thanks for finding that github issue